# Text over image positioning with css

Tags: html, css, image, text

[image]

how to put text over image "here"?
it must be 20px right from wrap, with fixed with of 250px.

**HTML**

```
<div class="background-image">
    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="pasta-town">
    <div id="motto" class="wrap">
        <div>some motto</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#motto {
font-size: 26px;
font-family: "MetaProMedium";
position: absolute; 
top:0;
}
#motto div {
left: 755px;
width: 250px;
}
.background-image {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.background-image > img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if you are using image means try html image map options.!

Comment: What is the parent of `here` box? `td` ? `div`? or..what?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the z-index for both the div containing the image and the text you want to posi The higher z-index will layer over the lower one.